# PHP function with func_get_args to insert tuples into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a PHP function with func_get_args to insert data into MySQL. The first parameter is the table, then the field and value. It only works with 3 parameters, but not with more.

```
public function createDato($list)
{
    try
    {
        $numArgs = func_num_args()/2;
        $argList = func_get_args();
        $j=1;
        if (func_num_args() < 3) die("No se han pasado suficientes elementos");
        $query = "INSERT INTO $argList[0] SET";
        for ($i = 1; $i < $numArgs; $i++) {
            $query .=" $argList[$i] = ?";
        }           
        $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);           
        for ($i; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) {
            $this->stmt->bindParam($j, $argList[$i]);
            $j++;
        }
        if($this->stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "<br>".func_get_arg(0)." creados";
        }
        else
            die('<br>Error creando tupla');
    }
    catch (PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you've looked at an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before you end up writing your own by accident. This sort of code is very, very hard to get working correctly, and even harder to make secure. You're not escaping column names properly here, so this is going to be trouble. Converting exceptions to easily ignored error messages is an example of how you're already digging yourself a deep hole here.

Comment: I had never used an ORM, I understand that they are PHP libraries to facilitate working with DB. What would be the simplest to start using an ORM ??

Comment: An ORM helps a lot because it gives you a bunch of tools to get started, plus ways of managing changes to your database schema over time. I've linked to three there, have a look and see which one feels like the best fit, or look around for others. Most modern [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) come with something like that built-in. The simplest way to start using one is to look at the introduction documentation and follow along with their examples.